# How to catch a groovy thrown exception within java?

Tags: java, exception, groovy

I am trying to extend some legacy code to make it more tolerant of network outages. I have some (legacy) groovy code which wraps up a call to a webservice (CallWebService) via wslite. Sometimes, this call throws either a wslite.http.HTTPClientException or a java.net.ConnectException exception (this has been determined by adding 
`log.info("Exception " + ex.getClass().getName() + " throw");` 
to my log4j logging)

The code which calls this groovy code is in java and looks like the following:

```
public static String getDataFromWebService(String webServiceUrl, String referenceNumber) {
try {       
    ReturnedData returnedData = new CallWebService(webServiceUrl, referenceNumber);
    return (String)returnedData.toXml();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    log.info("Exception caught: class of exception is " + ex.getClass().getName());
    throw ex;
}
```

What I want to do, is catch the thrown exception (wslite.http.HTTPClientException or java.net.ConnectException) and retry the call (as it's probably a glitch) once or twice.

When I try and add

```
catch (java.net.ConnectException ex)
```

and build, the build fails with

```
exception ConnectException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

What should I do to be able to catch and react to the appropriate exceptions?

Comment: that compiler error is telling you ConnectException is a checked exception which is not declared by anything inside the catch block.  are you sure you have the right exception?

Comment: sure? no, but I got my log4j code to do the following: log.info("Exception " + ex.getClass().getName() + " throw"); and it seemed to give me java.net.ConnectException as the name of the exception

Comment: is that the "top-level" exception, or was it nested within another exception (e.g. the HTTPClientException)?

Comment: exclude the naivety but, how could I tell?

Comment: aha, it'll let me catch an HTTPException which is a step in the right direction... thanks for the clues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Java code, I would do something like this:

```
try {
  callGroovy();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {  // EDIT --- Should be Exception, RuntimeException
  if (e instanceof HTTPClientException || e.getCause() instanceof ConnectException) {
    throw e;
  }
  // log other exception...
}
```

This would be a bit safer than catching single exception types.  In my experience, dynamic languages like groovy are more likely to throw unanticipated runtime exceptions.  And catching all runtime exceptions would ensure that groovy exceptions do not infect the rest of your program.

Comment: It doesn't even seem to throw a runtime exception, just gets bubbled up into an Exception. Within the exception handling I can then do the instance of comparison. Not idea but...

Comment: Oops. Meant to put Exception as the catch-ed type, not RuntimeException, but looks like you get the idea.